# Truncate string backwards 3 levels

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the string `C:/Users/Me/some/random/folder/test/public/uploads/avatars\\CY4tDgB4iXfb4MTF4.png` (notice the double backslashes)

How can I make it become `/public/uploads/avatars/CY4tDgB4iXfb4MTF4.png`? No matter what comes after `/avatars/[...]` or before `[...]/public/` it should convert it like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp), [slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp), [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace the `\\` with `/`, and then get the slice of the string starting at the index of `/public/`:

```
x = "C:/Users/Me/some/random/folder/test/public/uploads/avatars\CY4tDgB4iXfb4MTF4.png"
x = x.replace('\\', '/');
return x.slice(x.indexOf('/public/'))
```